# Installing python solidity parser from github and getting an error

Tags: python, installation, dependencies, antlr, solidity

I am trying to install and use [python solidity parser by ConsenSys](https://github.com/ConsenSys/python-solidity-parser), the pip3 installation gives no error but when I try to import the module it says

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/seed/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/python-solidity-parser/solidity_parser/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .parser import parse_file, parse, objectify, visit
  File "/home/seed/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/python-solidity-parser/solidity_parser/parser.py", line 10, in <module>
    from solidity_parser.solidity_antlr4.SolidityLexer import SolidityLexer
  File "/home/seed/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/python-solidity-parser/solidity_parser/solidity_antlr4/SolidityLexer.py", line 783, in <module>
    class SolidityLexer(Lexer):
NameError: name 'Lexer' is not defined
```

I tried to manually install it and made sure I have the required dependencies. I also installed antlr4 and downloaded required solidity grammar. I am using python 3.5.2 on ubuntu 16.

Answer (score 1):

I could not reproduce it. Here's what I did:

```
mkdir solidity-parser-test
cd solidity-parser-test
python3 -m venv env
source env/bin/activate
pip3 install solidity_parser
python3 test.py test.sol
```

where the last command will print the following:

```
{'children': [{'name': 'solidity',
               'type': 'PragmaDirective',
               'value': '>=0.5.0<0.7.0'},
              {'baseContracts': [],
               'kind': 'contract',
               'name': 'Coin',
               'subNodes': [],
               'type': 'ContractDefinition'}],
 'type': 'SourceUnit'}
```

`test.py` is this:

```py
import sys
import pprint

from solidity_parser import parser

sourceUnit = parser.parse_file(sys.argv[1])
pprint.pprint(sourceUnit)
```

and `test.sol` looks like this:

```
pragma solidity >=0.5.0 <0.7.0;

contract Coin {
}
```

Note: tested with Python version is 3.7.6

Comment: If I follow the same steps I get
 `File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    from solidity_parser import parser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'solidity_parser'`

I have to use sudo for pip3 install otherwise it gives me error `......File "/usr/lib/python3.5/zipfile.py", line 1093, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file`

I don't know what I am doing wrong or if there is a dependency that I am not meeting:(